# Get AccessToken with JavaScript from LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, access-token

I am developing a LinkedIn app with Javascript. Is there a way to authenticate a user without requiring him to click on a button and get his access token which can be sended to my server with Javascript?

I've only found this solution: https://gist.github.com/jsjohnst/efc88a38da25ff4e9283 but the shared secret can be viewed by all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time the user logs in to your application, they will need to click the button. This is impossible to bypass. If you add `authorize: true` to your Linkedin initialization code, they will not need to click the button for subsequent times. Code below:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: YOUR_API_KEY
    authorize: true
</script>
```

As for sending the access token to your server, you will need to exchange the Javascript API tokens with a REST API OAuth token, as described in this document: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/exchange-jsapi-tokens-rest-api-oauth-tokens

I hope this helps.

Comment: @Samer Bechara, link not working, is there any other source of documentation for the same ?